# What is "Map Execution Paths Through Application"?

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, owasp

I am reading the OWASP Test Guide v4 to learn how to pentest a web application. In the documentation, there is a section called "[Map execution paths through application (OTG-INFO-007)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Map_execution_paths_through_application_(OTG-INFO-007))".

I'm not sure that I understand the title. Is it about having all the paths and therefore the structure of the web application or is it something else I don't understand?

Comment: You don't understand the title, but do you understand the rest of the page? It explains what it is, what is expected, and how to test.

Comment: Yes ! i read the entire page and now it's alright.

Answer (score -1):

> is it about having all the paths and therefore the structure of the
>   web application or is it something else I don't understand?

Mapping all the paths (eg. `/execOnOpen/`) where something is executed, trough the application by laying out the tree-structure of the web-application with directory bruteforcing tools.

Comment: Note that in /execOnOpen/ is a file called index.php or whatever that is interpreted.

Comment: Ok so this step give information about the structure of the web app ?

Comment: This step is also called spidering, searching the site for existing paths, files etc where there is life. "so this step give information about the structure of the web app?" - the structure doesn't really matter that's just a visualisation, it just searches for files, things, dirs.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer i understand now !

Comment: This answer is wrong. You are confusing file paths with execution paths.

Comment: @schroeder I'm referring to a directory where there is a file that can be executed